# Definition of tautological action

Tags: group-theory, terminology, semigroups, group-actions

What is the precise meaning of the term 'tautological action' as used for example in [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_semigroup) in the context of semigroup actions?

For reference the particular sentence is: "A transformation semigroup of a set has a tautological semigroup action on that set. Such actions are characterized by being effective, i.e., if two elements of the semigroup have the same action, then they are equal."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like this terminology. What it appears to mean is the following: you can think of a transformation semigroup either concretely as a collection of functions from a set $S$ to itself closed under composition, or abstractly as an abstract semigroup $G$ (namely the functions above) together with a faithful (effective) action of $G$ on $S$. The tautological action is this action.

Comment: What don't you like about the term, is it misleading? Is there a better term for it?

Comment: It's just not very descriptive. I don't know a better term. I just wouldn't talk about transformation semigroups in the first place.

Comment: I just found that in Bourbaki's Algebra I, page 25 example 3, they refer to this action as the _canonical action_.

Comment: The answer to the question of the original post ist still unclear. Can anbody else comment on this?